# read content from flash and save it on to server an Image using java,jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

i am embedding flash in jsp using following code  so as to activate webcam but i want to read an Image from that object tag using java,jsp or jscript and want save it on to server directory
HOw can we do this?

```
<object id="whatever" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="282" height="180"codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,115,0">
<param name="src" value="./swf/capturecam.swf"/>
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF"/>
<param name="quality" value="best"/>
<embed name="whatever" src="./swf/capturecam.swf" width="282" height="180" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="best" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: i am able to do it using actionscript 3 but for saving it pops up save dialogue box which I don't want and uses PHP to send it to server

Comment: please help me! anybody know how to do it?